# RuntimeError on Mac trying python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Some strange problems occurred when executing the codes:

```
# a lot more
bank_info = p.map(itr_banks, range(len(bank_sites)))

bank_info = sum(bank_info, [])
# a lot more
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
......
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
......
```

What makes it strange is that the almost same code run a year ago doesn't throw any error. The project was created a year ago and this time is a slight refactor. The python version may be changed but still using PyCharm.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code and instructions or data necessary to reproduce the problem. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to refer to [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).